# SBT-like features in the Haskell build ecosystem

Tags: scala, haskell, sbt, cabal

I've been using Scala with SBT quite a bit lately. The REPL loop of has a handy feature: `~ COMMAND`, meaning perform COMMAND for every source file change in the project. For instance:

```
~ test
```

and

```
~ compile
```

are *terrifically* useful for rapid development. I wonder, does anyone know of something similar for Haskell, a cabal shell, maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get something like this very easily using [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

Just fire up a terminal in your project directory and run something like this:

```
$ while inotifywait -qq -r -e modify .; do cabal build && ./dist/build/tests/tests; done
```

This also works for any other language; just insert the build commands of your choice.

Comment: its 2021 and this is still a better option than `ghcid` because it doesn't do anything to overcome ghc's lack of support for multiple components. IE ghcid can watch *just* tests, but then if src files change, it won't catch it; only when test files change.

Answer (score 3):

You can script ghci to both define your own commands, and augment existing commands. To do this:

- [define a ~/.ghci file](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html)
- write a macro using `:def` to replace e.g. `:reload`

More info on GHCi `:def` commands is [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html).

Comment: I think this misses the mark somewhat. The aim is to loop arbitrary cabal commands triggered on source changes; achieving this aim through GHCi seems backward. What does GHCi know of "cabal test", for instance? A "cabal-shell" equivalent to SBT is slightly more than a rejiggered GHCi macro; cabal has more information about the project than GHCi, no? Thank you for the resource, all the same.

Comment: Ah, OK. So that's a bit different. Yes, hooking up something with inotify and cabal build might be fun.

Answer (score 3):

The [ghcid](https://github.com/ndmitchell/ghcid#readme) project provides something limited to `~ :reload`. It provides a few extra features (format to a fixed number of lines, persist warnings from previously loaded files), but not the generality of running any command.